# Calorie content of foods

Tags: nutrition, weight-loss, calories

I'm trying to regulate my calorie intake. I cook for myself and I need some reliable information on calorie content of typical foods I eat so I can adjust the portions in such way I actually lose weight.

The foods I'm interested in:

1. meat: pork(neck, leg, fat), beef (sirloin, rib-eye), chicken (legs, breast, wings), lamb meat, fish (trout, carp, salmon)
2. grains and seeds: white bread (wheat flour), polenta (corn flour), rice (boiled), beans, chickpeas, sweet peas
3. vegetables: potatoes, carrots, cucumbers, spinach, tomatoes, etc.
4. sugars: beet sugar, honey
5. dairy products: milk (3.5%fat), yogurt, sour cream (15-25% fat)
6. fruits: bananas, watermelon, cantaloupe, apples, pears, peaches, etc.
7. eggs
8. cooking oils and pork fat

I'd be happy with partial answers, or answers containing data for things I didn't mention, as long as they are easy to find in the stores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the most comprehensive and practical tool to check for calorie content of foods is [USDA Food Composition Database](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods). You can find calorie content for baked chicken, fried chicken, breaded chicken...which is not the same. It also lists the main nutrient composition of every food (carbohydrates, proteins, fats, minerals, vitamins).

You can also search by some food ingredients, such as flour or sugar, and by nutrients, such as protein, fat and carbohydrates.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I wonder if there is a database that can be downloaded into Access or Excel.

Comment: Look at the loseit or myfitnesspal apps if you want to be able to relatively accurately track the calories you eat.